# What's the maximum number of enchantments an item can have in Dungeons of Dredmor?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

When enchanting items with anvils of Krong is there a limit to the number of enchantments allowed or number of times an item can be used with anvils? If there is, do the bonus enchantments from using more lutefisk at a lutefisk statue count towards that limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is effectively unlimited (except probably by how many different stats are available).

When you factor in the possible results of using an Anvil of Krong on previously enchanted objects or the (currently bugged so it adds extra enchantments in some cases) "This Translation is All Wrong!" Archaeology ability it is possible to get items with *lots* of enchantments.

Here's a fun image demonstrating this, taken from a [post](http://www.gaslampgames.com/forum/discussion/comment/2712#Comment_2712) on the official forum:

[image: Dungeons of Dredmor: A slightly overpowered crossbox...]

Comment: Never played the game and I'm just curious if you can explain what all the icons mean, mostly for giggles.

Comment: @Shinrai The top row is all types of bonus elemental damage. The second row is resistances. The third row is stat bonuses to the primary stats Burliness, Nimbleness, and Savvy. The fourth row is bonuses to the secondary stats mana, melee power, counter, enemy dodge reduction, damage absorb, health regen, mana regen, wand use, and trap affinity. The number of stars is the base items rarity.

Comment: Why does any game need that many elements?! o.O

Comment: For fun! I rather enjoy wielding a hammer that deals bonus Existential and Transmutative damage.